# mac ターミナルでインストールしてきたものを表示する方法と削除する方法を教えてください

Tags: linux, macos, homebrew

ターミナルにコードを入力してインストールしたものが今までたくさんあるのですが、インストールの仕方が悪かったのか、使いたいツールにエラーが発生してしまいました。そこで今までターミナルでインストールしてきたものの一覧を表示できる方法が知りたいです。あと指定した項目またはインストールしてきたもの全てを削除する方法も知りたいです

Comment: ターミナルからのインストールといっても、いくつか方法が存在します。どういったコマンドで主にインストールしてきたか、もう少し具体的に「どのコマンドでどのアプリケーションをインストールしたか」を書いていただいた方がより的確なアドバイスを得やすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Homebrewでインストールしたパッケージを削除したい、という質問でしたら、
brew uninstall パッケージ名
です。

削除する前に、
brew list
でインストール済みのパッケージ一覧を確認すれば良いでしょう。

Comment: homebrewでないところでインストールしたものはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: それは、あなたが何をどのようなコマンドでインストールしたのかによります。
情報不足で答えようがないです。
具体的に何をどうしたいのか、質問文を補足しましょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます　他のもできるようになりました　例えばpip listと入力したら表示されるようになりました